# Proper Noun Taxonomy

Tags: api, taxonomy

Is there any API which maps proper noun to its category?

For eg: Albert Einstein can be mapped to physicist/scientist. The TextWise API and the Alchemy API are used for text only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend suggested the Freebase API: http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_API
That works for me.
Thanks